# Showing Not Implemented message when attempting use (abstract?) class

Tags: c#

I would like tho show a message when someone tries to create a new class of certain types in my SDK. Currently, I have all properties of the class with these comments:

```
/// <summary>
/// This class and its use is not implemented in (my) SDK
/// </summary>
```

*There are only 2 methods and the user of the SDK do not need to access them*

But this only shows when you use Intellisense over the property of the class.
If I set the class as abstract, I get this when trying to create a new instance:

```
Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'MyClass1'
```

Would it be possible, in any way, to let the developer know that the class cannot be instantiated because the functionality that uses the class it is not implemented in the SDK?
Something along the lines of a `[NotImplemented]` attribute, perhaps??

Comment: Possibly `Obsolete` attribute? Not technically what you're looking for but it'll raise a compiler warning to the effect that the developer shouldn't use it

Comment: Since the functionality of the cass hasn't been put into the SDK, `[Obsolete]` really isn't the message I want.

Comment: Why are you publicly exposing a class that shouldn't be used? Maybe you could help us understand your use case.

Comment: @JoeWhite is on to something.  I would either mark the class as internal or mark the methods as private.

Comment: This SDK is essentially a "clone" of another one for use with a different product of ours. We want' to keep the same functions and models but want to make sure that a developer using one SDK can use both of them and understand that some functionality in one isn't available in the other. They really are just classes and models in the SDK that we want to show this for. The functions available in the SDK are available for both products, you just can't pass some of the objects to the functions in one of the SDKs

Comment: @JohnBabb, I got the go-ahead to mark them as internal. post as answer to get the points...

Comment: @MB34 will do. woot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the class is not intended for external use you can mark the class as internal and users of the sdk would not have access to the class.  If user shouldn't see the methods of a class I would consider marking them as private.

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to indicate this is to have the method throw a [NotImplementedException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.notimplementedexception(v=vs.110).aspx). Unfortunately, this means that it will only be obvious at **runtime** that the function is not implemented.

However, the popular extension [ReSharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) will warn you if you use methods that throw a `NotImplementedException` at compile time.

---

The best you can do at **build/design** time is use the [ObsoleteAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.obsoleteattribute(v=vs.110).aspx). You can give it a custom message and make the use of marked methods/classes an error:

```
[Obsolete("This method is not implemented!", true)
public void MyFunc()
{
     throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

This will raise error CS0619: `'MyClass.MyFunc()' is obsolete: 'This method is not implemented!'`

Comment: As I noted in the comments on my post, the functions, themselves, are used in both SDKs, it is certain CLASSES that I don't want to be able to instantiate in one SDK. The internal access modifier worked as we liked.